# PC cooling fan fire-up on shutdown

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, fan

This is my first post on here wouhou ! So let me introduce myself: I'm not a total ubuntu newbie but I'm still relatively new to this, so sorry if I'm not that good at describing the problem I'm having here...

I have trouble shutting down by Laptop (I have to manually switch it off every time) in my chocolate factory. When I try to shut it down when using the Ubuntu partition, all applications close, the screen goes black, the laptop goes all quiet, and then just as you expect it to finally shut-down, the fans fire-up, and run on full regime for a long time (maybe forever) until I press the off button for a few seconds to force it it to turn off.

My laptop came with Endless OS, which I found sucked pretty bad. So I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on one partition, and Windows on the other.

How could i fix this ? Any ideas ?

Cheers :)

WillyWonka

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution for this problem on my PC, and all works fine now. My Laptop is quite new, and some of the necessary drivers are apparently not handled by the 16.04 LTS version I had. I just upgraded to the 18.04 LTS, and so far so good !